# PostgreSQL + Rails citext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, case-insensitive

I am trying to move to heroku which uses PostgreSQL 8.4 which has a citext column type which is nice since the app was written for MySQL.

Is there any way to use :citext with rails (so that if the migrations are run on MySQL the citext would just use string/text?

I found this ticket, but it seems like it isn't going to be a part of rails for a while:
https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3174-add-support-for-postgresql-citext-column-type

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Rails 4.2+

Rails 4.2 has native support for the `citext` column type.

#### Rails < 4.2

If you're using Rails < 4.2, you can try using the [activerecord-postgresql-citext](https://github.com/braintree/activerecord-postgresql-citext) gem.

This allows you to write migrations like this:

```
def up
  enable_extension("citext")                   

  create_table :models, :force => true do |t|  
    t.citext :name                             
    t.timestamps                               
  end                                          
end
```

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, Rails now has native support for the `citext` column type (since 4.2).

To migrate existing columns you need to enable the citext extension and then `change_column`. Change colum is non-reversible so you'll need separate `up` and `down` methods.

```rb
class ConvertUserNameToCaseInsensitive < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    enable_extension 'citext' # only the first migration you add a citext column
    change_column :user, :name, :citext
  end

  def down
    change_column :user, :name, :string
    disable_extension 'citext' # reverse order, only the first migration you add a citext column (this will be the last time you remove one in a rollback)
  end
end
```

Disable extension is only required the last time you remove a citext column when rolling back so rather than add ugly comments it might be better to have separate migrations and explain the reason why in your commit message:

```rb
# migration 1.rb
class EnableCitext < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    enable_extension 'citext'
  end
end


# migration 2.rb
class ConvertUserNameToCaseInsensitive < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    change_column :user, :name, :citext
  end

  def down
    change_column :user, :name, :string
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record. Seems like rails 4.2 has native support for this.

> Added support for the citext column type in the PostgreSQL adapter.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that Rails has only a limited vocabulary of data types. You will likely have to use good old-fashioned SQL to deal with any other types.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to change an existing `string` column to `citext`, try creating a migration

```
rails g migration change_username_from_string_to_citext
```

Then make the migration look like this

```
class ChangeUsernameFromStringToCitext < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    enable_extension("citext") # Don't forget this line
    change_column :users, :username, :citext
  end
end
```

Comment: `change_column` is [irreversible](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns) so there is no way to rollback with this solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56368026/145725 for an earlier answer that shows how to change an existing column in a reversible manner